# Add a Group E-mail command button to a Parameter Form in ms access 2010

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, parameters, email-attachments

```
I have an unbound parameter form based on a query called q_t_A.
```

Below you will see the code for the on click event of the command button cmdSendReport.

This attaches the report to a blank e-mail which allows me to choose the recipient.

I was wondering if I could add a cmdGroupSendReport button so that the report could be sent to a group of recipients.

In the underlying parameter form query q_t_A, I have a Yes/No field called EmailMailout, which singles out those who only want to have reports emailed to them.

I am planning on adding a checkbox parameter to the form chkEmailReportsOnly based on the Yes/No field EmailMailout so that if checked/true, only those email addresses will get the report sent to them by e-mail.

Is this the best way to do that? Secondly, how do I modify the code below so that All of the e-mail recipients receive the report shown in the combobox cboReports?

```
Private Sub cmdSendReport_Click()
If Not IsNull(cboReports) And cboReports <> "" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, Me.cboReports, acFormatPDF
Elsed
MsgBox ("Please make a Report selection first from the drop down list to the left.")
cboReports.SetFocus
End If
cboReports = ""
End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your help...I am really new to this and so very thankful for your suggestions.

Oblio

Answer (score 0):

Highlight 'SendObject' and click F1 to get Help. This object lets you add To, Cc, Bcc etc.

Loop through the records on your form, to create a string of email addresses to send To, eg:

```
Dim rs as recordset, s$
Set rs= Forms!chkEmailReportsOnly.RecordsetClone: With rs
    While not .EOF
        If !SendEmail then s = s & ";" & !Email
    Wend
.close: End with
Set rs= nothing
s=mid(s,2)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I apologize that I did not see this until now (SEP 2016).